# How do you make folders inside a command folder and make it work in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am currently wanting to make it so I can make folders inside my commands folder like moderation etc.
Just so I can clean it up more. However I really do not know how to do this as everytime I do it does not work.

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const client = new Discord.Client();

const commandFiles = readdirSync(join(__dirname, "commands")).filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

So this is my current code so far so if I make another folder and add an command there it will not work and won't boot up.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a function to recursively read files in a directory and all of its subdirectories.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

function readFiles(dir) {
    const paths = readdirSync(dir, { withFileTypes: true });

    return paths.reduce((files, path) => {
        if (path.isDirectory()) {
            files.push(...readFiles(join(dir, path.name)));
        } else if (path.isFile()) {
            files.push(join(dir, path.name));
        }

        return files;
    }, []);
}

const commandFiles = readFiles("commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(join(__dirname, file));
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Comment: I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of files.push"

Comment: thanks you. now i can actually keep my commands clean lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for loops to read every subdirectory and files in those subdirectories.
Let's say you have a `./commands` folder, and in that folder are more folders grouping your commands — moderation, fun, public, etc, and those folders contain your command files.

```
const cmdDirs = fs.readdirSync('./commands');

/* Loop through subdirectories in commands directory */
for (let dir of cmdDirs) {
    /* Read every subdirectory and filter for JS files */
    let commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${dir}`)
    .filter(f => f.endsWith('.js'));

    /* Loop through every file */
    for (let file of commandFiles) {
        /* Set command file */
        let command = require(`./commands/${dir}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you but where you say // set command file what do you mean by that? (sorry if i seem a bit dumb quite new to this)

Comment: it comes up with this: Error: Cannot find module './commands/admins/{file}'

Comment: Oops. Put a $ in front of `{file}`. So, `${file}`.